# count frequency of values by week using pandas then plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Lets say I have the following Time Series with an item:

```
df:
date       item
1/6/2021    apples
1/6/2021    apples
1/6/2021    oranges
1/6/2021    oranges
1/7/2021    oranges
1/8/2021    bananas
2/1/2021    apples
2/1/2021    apples
2/1/2021    apples
2/1/2021    apples
2/2/2021    oranges
2/3/2021    bananas
3/1/2021    apples
3/1/2021    apples
3/1/2021    apples
3/1/2021    apples
3/1/2021    oranges
3/2/2021    oranges
3/3/2021    bananas
```

I would like to make a count of each item and have it broken out by week then plot the results in a bar graph. week is Saturday to Saturday.

```
week of     item     count

1/9/2021    apples     2
           oranges     3
           bananas     1
        
2/6/2021    apples     4
            oranges    1
            bananas    1
        
3/6/2021    apples     4
            oranges    2
            bananas    1
```

I tried the following code:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='W')
   for name, group in weekly:
    print(group.item.unique(), group.item.count())
```

That was able to give me the list of items and the sum of all the items, but Im not sure how to get the sum of each item or plot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`groupby size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-size) on both [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html#pandas-grouper) and `item` (use [Anchored Offset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) to set Saturday to Saturday weekly):

```
# Convert date to datetime if not already
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SAT'), 'item'])
        .size()
        .to_frame(name='count')
)
```

`new_df`:

```
                    count
date       item          
2021-01-09 apples       2
           bananas      1
           oranges      3
2021-02-06 apples       4
           bananas      1
           oranges      1
2021-03-06 apples       4
           bananas      1
           oranges      2
```

---

Then to plot use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot) + [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# pivot to wide format
plot_df = (
    new_df.reset_index().pivot(index='date', columns='item', values='count')
)
# Plot Bar
ax = plot_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ylabel='count')
# Format X-axis ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FixedFormatter(plot_df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
)
plt.show()
```

Or straight to `plot_df` without `new_df`:

```
plot_df = (
    df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SAT'), 'item'])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count')
        .pivot(index='date', columns='item', values='count')
)

# Plot Bar
ax = plot_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ylabel='count')
# Format X-axis ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FixedFormatter(plot_df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['1/6/2021', '1/6/2021', '1/6/2021', '1/6/2021', '1/7/2021',
             '1/8/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '2/1/2021',
             '2/2/2021', '2/3/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021',
             '3/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '3/2/2021', '3/3/2021'],
    'item': ['apples', 'apples', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'bananas',
             'apples', 'apples', 'apples', 'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas',
             'apples', 'apples', 'apples', 'apples', 'oranges', 'oranges',
             'bananas']
})
# Convert date to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Straight to Plot DF
plot_df = (
    df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W-SAT'), 'item'])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count')
        .pivot(index='date', columns='item', values='count')
)
# Plot Bar
ax = plot_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ylabel='count')
# Format X-axis ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FixedFormatter(plot_df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thats really great! Thanks so I just needed to include the column in the groupby! How would you plot these items?